# How do you install dependencies

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, raspberrypi, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you install system dependencies? I thought rosmake, rosdep or catkin was capable of doing that, but I can't figure out how?

I am installing ROS on RaspberryPi and ros has good definitions for Debian already, but during install:

```
rosdep install -ay --os=debian:squeeze
```

isn't installing dependencies. I am doing it by hand through apt-get and it is painfully slow.

This questions is also related to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/46987/how-to-make-rosmake-and-distcc-work-together/) about building ROS for Debian on Raspberry Pi.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46968/how-do-you-install-dependencies/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-10-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is your ROS distribution?

Did you maybe forget to run rosdep init/rosdep update?

Otherwise rosdep is the right tool for this task. It should give you at least some output about what it is doing.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-10-29**:
Sorry, it is embedded in the post: Debian on the Raspberry Pi (ARM). Rosdep init and update are part of the Debian install directions. I think somehow there is an issue with Raspberry Pi ... rosdep install -a says everything is fine, but I keep having to install them by hand.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-29**:
I was referring to the ROS distribution as rosdep changed between electric and fuerte. It looks like fuerte. Besides the simple explanation that there are just no rosdep rules for your system your can try: rosdep install -v (verbose) and rosdep db should give you what rosdep has stored.